# Asp.Net How to databind on C#

Tags: asp.net

Work on Asp.net vs08 C#.My textBox is bellow,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="cssSingleTextbox" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"
         onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode==9);" Text='<%# Bind("DATE_BIRTH", "{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
```

this `Text='<%# Bind("DATE_BIRTH", "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")` .aspx code want to write on .cs page how to?

Answer (score 1):

I must say that I find your question a bit vague, but I'll try and give you an answer anyway and I hope that I have understood what you are trying to achieve.

`Bind` only works in the context of a databount control such a `GridView`, `Repeater` etc., and is used in datatemplates of those controls. Since you have only posted very little markup, this leads me to think that your `TextBox` is not within a datatemplate. Therefore you cannot use `Bind`. You can however do like this:

```
Text='<%= DATE_BIRTH.ToString("0:dd MMM yyyy") %>'
```

Given that your page has a member or propery of type `DateTime` with the name `DATE_BIRTH`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set databinding expressions from your cs code.
Alternatively, you could call a function in a databinding expression, and have it return different values depending on your situation.

```
Text='<%# YourFunction() %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct "answer" to your problem because direct binding to a control from C# is not using the Bind properties of ASP. You have to do it differently.
Allow me to explain.
Binding is a feature of ASP that unless you want to force things to be differently managed via javascript or fancy C#, then it's predominantly best to use it as it was designed to be used, which is via ASP and not so much code-behind in C# (or VB for that matter).

I suggest you read these web pages thoroughly to understand what Binding is all about ...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860

and

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_databinding.asp

In a direct response to your issue, you cannot send mark-up language code into a Text property because it will not be converted to "code" for you. What you're trying to do is basically create code at run-time, and it does not work the way you stated. Sending text strings to a control's Text property is essentially just that - giving it a string. It means nothing to the program itself.

Essentially to solve your problem as direct as possible (assuming a lot here) you need to code it similar to this in your C# program (somewhere, it's up to you) ...

```
   SqlConnection cnn = new 
       SqlConnection("server=(local);database=<YOURDATABASE>;"); 
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from authors", cnn); //replace this with your SQL of course
   DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
   da.Fill(ds, "authors"); //replace this with your table name
   Repeater1.DataSource = ds.Tables["authors"]; //ditto
   Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Now this is assuming you're using a Repeater1 control in your ASP page. You will have to determine what it is you're trying to put the data into.

This ..

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="cssSingleTextbox" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode==9);" Text='<%# Bind("DATE_BIRTH", "{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
```

Should become more like this ..

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DATE_BIRTH") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

And somewhere above this you need to specifiy a container that holds your textbox (like a GridView of FormView) and that has to have an SqlDatasource reference.

I won't keep adding code here for the sake of spoon feeding you, but you need to read up on the above links and you'll soon understand how it's meant to work.

Good luck

Comment: That answer cost me 2 hours of research and testing to answer something meaningful, and I get nothing for it!? Come on.